# The usage of uses-feature tag in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have read somewhere that using 'uses-feature' node prevents the app being installed on a device which does not support a specified feature. But when I visited developer's guide at
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element , I read :

Declared  elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application. However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's  declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application. For this reason, it's very important that you declare all of the features (from the list below) that your application uses.

So if I specify a feature like NFC in this node, and consider that my app is being shared on a third-party sharing platform like Shareit and the target device does not support NFC ,will the app be installable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
Apparently uses feature node does not prevent any installation however in some platforms like google play it functions as a filter